# How to make an image array move?

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsarray

I have an image array of two images that repeat to make a bird flapping wings.

How can I make the array move?

I have this for the array:

```
NSArray *imageNames = @[@"bird1.png", @"bird2.png"];

NSMutableArray *birdflapping = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
    [birdflapping addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 193)];
animationImageView.animationImages = birdflapping;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 1;

[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
[animationImageView startAnimating];
```

How can I make the array (as a whole) move?

Comment: What's meaning for the array move? delete from array or animation move?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *animationArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"images1.jpg"],
                                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"images5.jpg"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"index3.jpg"],
                        nil];
    UIImageView *animationView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460)];
        animationView.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
        animationView.animationImages=animationArray;
        animationView.animationDuration=1.5;
    animationView.animationRepeatCount=0;
        [animationView startAnimating]; 
        [self.view addSubview:animationView];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the animated image that you want to move, and that image is drawn by and contained in the image view. To move the image, you could move the image view. One way to do that is to adjust the position of the view's `center` property. Another possibility is to use a larger number of images, with each frame in the animation showing the bird moved forward a bit.

That said, there are much better ways to do what you want. You should look into sprite animation using either SpriteKit or Cocos2D.

Comment: ok thanks, I think i'm going to look into Cocos2D, I've heard a lot about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
UIImageView * animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200,200)];

 NSArray *imageNames = @[@"bird1.png", @"bird2.png"];
animTime =.0;
[animatedImageView setAnimationImages:imageNames] ;
animatedImageView.animationDuration =  animTime;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: I want to make a flappy bird like effect, the bird's wings flap and if the user touches the screen it moves down, do you know how to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation if all you want is a simple move entire bird across the screen in a line.

Something like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    // move bird as a whole, 300 units across the screen
    self.animationImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(300,0);
}];
```